# Ambiguous column in field, but when I prefix, it says 'unknown'

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT table1.user_id as uID, table1.password AS pass, table1.libID AS user_id, table2.firstname, lockout.loginAttempts, lockout.lastAttemptTime
    FROM( SELECT 'johnDoe' user ) u 
    LEFT JOIN table1 a 
    ON u.user = a.username 
    INNER JOIN table2
    ON table1.libID = table2.user_id 
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT attemptedUsername, loginAttempts, lastAttemptTime
        FROM lockout 
        WHERE accountType = 'public' 
    ) l 
    ON u.user = l.attemptedUsername
```

Originally, I hadn't prefixed the column names in the field list with the table names, but since both table1 and table have columns named user_id - mysql gave me the 'ambiguous' error for user_id.

After prefixing, I'm getting the error

```
Unknown column 'songbookdbpal_users.user_id' in 'field list'
```

The column definitely exists - is there somewhere I'm tripping up in the syntax?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you gave `table1` an alias, you have to use that in the rest of the query:

```
SELECT a.user_id as uID, a.password AS pass, a.libID AS user_id, 
        table2.firstname, lockout.loginAttempts, lockout.lastAttemptTime
FROM( SELECT 'johnDoe' user ) u 
LEFT JOIN table1 a 
ON u.user = a.username 
INNER JOIN table2
ON a.libID = table2.user_id 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT attemptedUsername, loginAttempts, lastAttemptTime
    FROM lockout 
    WHERE accountType = 'public' 
) l 
ON u.user = l.attemptedUsername
```